# dojo dynamic resizing of widgets

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I'm a dojo beginner and got a "huge" project on the table which uses dojo 1.3.2 (upgrading to a newer version is atm not possible). I'm consuming the documentation as far as possible for this old version and I'm making progress, but there are still corners in the dojo maze I'm not aware of or I don't understand completely. I hope my question will not be a duplicate since I couldn't find a answer to my question yet.

In the project is a widget which will get visible or hidden. At some user-actions the widget should resize dynamically. I achieved a logic for that by using `dojo.query` (to access the right dom nodes) and `dojo.style` (for doing the actual resizing) and this works fine so far.

There is just one problem: if the widget gets shown for the first time it has a default size (which comes from html) although the function gets called via onShown-function of the widget. My reiszing logic will only affect the widget after a user-action happened that causes a resizing or the next time the widget will be shown.

Is there anything where I should look into which could cause such behavior by standard? I would appreciate every hint, since I can't tell if there are dependecies through the project which cause this behavior. Anyway this seems for me to be related to dojo and it's logic, since trying a second call ect does not help.

Thanks!

Comment: To give this question some kind of ending without really having a answer for the old stuff: This year we finally could upgrade the dojo version to 1.10 and the code I already had worked very well and did what I expected. So this seems to be an problem specific to the old version. Assuming this will be not of interest for the most developers nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on the dijit lifecycle:

O'Reilly's definitive guide is really out of date, but this is actually a good thing for 1.3.2:
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001819/ch12.html#the_widget_lifecycle

The nearest Dojo docs I can find are for 1.6, but should basically apply:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dijit/_Widget.html

You want to look at startup() - that's important, as startup() is the first lifecycle method where the widget is expected to be placed in the DOM.

Comment: This is helpful information for me, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem. To do my resizing I need a specific domNode which is not referenced directly in the instance the code is placed. I get this domNode with `dojo.query` and this works all fine. Following your hint about startup() I moved the searching code in this place since there it would be executed only once (I did this in onShow before) and the nodes are found. Calling my resize() in this method doesn't seem to change the already described behaviour. Resizing still happens just on next show or user action. Any idea?